# Trying to pad decimal number with leading spaces

Tags: c#, decimal, string-formatting, format-string, padleft

```
for (int iCount = 0; iCount < oForm.LineItems.Count; iCount++)
           {
```

// cartDetails is a stringbuilder here.

```
     cartDetails.Append(String.Format("{0:0}", oForm.LineItems[iCount].Quantity));
     cartDetails.Append(String.Format("{0:0.00}", oForm.LineItems[iCount].Price));
     cartDetails.Append(String.Format("{0:0.00}", oForm.LineItems[iCount].ExtendedPrice));

     //cartDetails.Append(string.Format("{0,10:#,##0.00}", oForm.LineItems[iCount].Price) + "</TD><TD>");
     //cartDetails.Append(string.Format("{0,10:#,##0.00}", oForm.LineItems[iCount].ExtendedPrice) + "</TD><TD>");
     //cartDetails.Append(String.Format("{0}", oForm.LineItems[iCount].Quantity).PadLeft(4)+ "</TD><TD>");
     //cartDetails.Append(String.Format("{0:0.00}", oForm.LineItems[iCount].Price).PadLeft(8) + "</TD><TD>");
```

I have pastd the source code I am using. I add qty, price, extendedprice and all are decimal columns. All I am looking to do is to pad left with leading spaces. Decimal rounding to 2 digits seems to be happening.

Those commented lines above are some of the other options I have tried.
Currently if qty has values such as 4 and 40, they don't get aligned when I print them in a table. Same with price.

CAn someone please suggest what am I doing here?

**Update1:** Tried Lucas suggestion, but it is not working. Here is what I am geting.

cartDetails.Append(String.Format("{0:0,10}", oForm.LineItems[iCount].Quantity));

When I try the above, it shows 10 for every line irrespective of the value in oForm.LineItems[iCount].Quantity.

And if I change 
String.Format("{0:0,4}", it shows 04 for all the records

Comment: Why not use `AppendFormat`?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: Can you provide me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remark:** This is for alignemend in caracter based representation such as text files

Have a look at the last section in [composite formatting (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx).

First format the number as desired and the pad the result

```
cartDetails.AppendFormat("{0,4}", // padding with spaces
    String.Format("{0:0}", oForm.LineItems[iCount].Quantity));  // format number
```

**Addtition:** If you want to position your data in a html table you should use css (or inline styles)

```
<td class="right">This is right aligned</td>
```

with css

```
.right { text-align: right; }
```

or inlined:

```
<td style="text-align: right">This is right aligned</td>
```

Comment: cartDetails.Append(String.Format("{0:0,10}", oForm.LineItems[iCount].Quantity));              When I try this, it shows 10 for every line irrespective of the value in oForm.LineItems[iCount].Quantity.        And if I change to String.Format("{0:0,4}", it shows 04 for all the records.

Comment: Ok I see, only strings are padded with spaces. Will update my sample.

Comment: I see that text-align is important here which I had missed.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `AppendFormat` method instead of appending formatted string.
Also correct format will be `{index,padding:format}`. And consider to use `foreach` instead of `for`:

```
foreach (var lineItem in oForm.LineItems)
{ 
    cartDetails.AppendFormat("{0,4:0}", lineItem.Quantity);
    cartDetails.AppendFormat("{0,10:0.00}", lineItem.Price);
    // etc
}
```

Comment: I tried your approach and for lineItem.Price which has decimal place it doesn't trim to 2 digits and if it is even number (say 157) it doesn't output as 157.00.           I tried with foreach but lineItem doesn't show quantity, price within lineitem.

Comment: @NewCoder just verified - `{0,10:0.00}` trims decimal to 2 digits. I.e. `34.123` will be displayed as `34.12`. Verify your code.

Comment: It trims to 2 digits but when it is 157, it doesn't output as 157.00.

Comment: @NewCoder verify your code. `0.00` will format 157 as `157.00`. `0.##` will format 157 as `157`

Comment: It works fine now. Can you suggest why does lineItem doesn't work when I use foreach loop. Thanks.

Comment: @NewCoder it depends.. What type lineItems has? What type of LineItems collection?